# How do I apply a font resizer to list elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jQuery font resizer on this page:

```
http://192.196.159.46/we-educate/solar
```

and it works well on the p tags. However, the list elements are not impacted by this.

How do I modify the following code to include list elements?

```
$('div#article > p').jfontsize({
btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-minus',
btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-default',
btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-plus',
btnMinusMaxHits: 5,
btnPlusMaxHits: 8,
sizeChange: 5
});
```

I tried the following without success:

```
$('div#article > ul > li').jfontsize({
btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-minus',
btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-default',
btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-plus',
btnMinusMaxHits: 5,
btnPlusMaxHits: 8,
sizeChange: 5
});
```

I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('div#article li')` as your selector.

Answer (score 1):

How about `$("div#article")`? That affects all parts of your div.

Comment: good idea, but in this case it is overwhelming and includes the resizer.